# Why are these color patches/rings coming in the blender video output while the image rendering is very clean

Tags: rendering

I am making a simple material from an image. Attached below is my node settings. I am mixing one BSDF color on top of the image texture (this is just to create an illusion of some haze/atmospheric effect - kindly do not suggest to change this basic design itself since it is linked to other things in the project, not in my control).

[image: Shader node settings]

I have used the Layer Weight node to gradually increase the mix towards the edges, and very light/ almost nil in front of the camera. The mixing is good in image render. Attached below is the image after the render. It looks ok to me. This is in png format.

[image: Output of Image Render]

I have then rendered the image sequence for the scene. Then I made the video in blender itself, from the image sequences. But the quality is very poor in the final video. Attached below is one screenshot for the same frame above. See how some circular rings appear in this video output. If we inspect minutely, those rings are present even in the image render. But it is hardly noticeable in the image, it is almost ok. After the video is made, the rings are easily visible and it is not within any acceptable range. Can someone help me to get rid of these rings in the video output ? Anything close to the above image quality is acceptable to me.

[image]

Just so that you can compare, I have attached below the output without the Mix node. This is just the plain image alone.

[image: Image output without the Mixer node]

**Things that I have tried so far (without any result):**

1. First obvious thought is to try different settings in the video output. I have used ffmpeg option, x264 encoder, Lossless output, 1920x1080 resolution above. I tried changing these options, without any luck. For example, changing the encoder to HuffYUV or MPEG-4 resulted in no better quality in the video. Also changing the framerate had no impact.
2. I have used the command line input for ffmpeg to directly convert the image sequence into a video without using blender. It resulted into the same video quality irrespective of what bitrate or what encoder I use. I went up as high as 20M bitrate, resulting in much bigger file size, but the output quality remained where it is. Finally I tried to directly mux the png output files in a video container using ffmpeg without any encoding. This gave little better result, but the output file size is 100 times bigger. Obviously that cannot be accepted since a video of one minute will cross 4-5 GB in size. Moreover, the output video was only little better, still not close to the png image quality.
3. I have opened the png image in MS Paint and simply saved it as a jpeg file. The png file is 5 MB while the jpg was just 200-300 kb. Still, the quality did not degrade (at least to the viewer's eyes). This means, there has to be a way to compress the png files and create a video without compromising too much on the quality. It technically seems possible as the jpeg was equally good, with much lesser size. But I could not figure out any possible way to actually achieve that in the video.

Any suggestion to overcome this hurdle either in the blender node settings, blender render or in video codec/compression, will be highly appreciated. Spent 3 full days/nights without any sleep and still struggling. Help me guys!

Comment: Have you tried rendering all the images as a sequence and then attaching them in the video editor?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. I have the image sequence, I have the video, and they differ in quality.

Comment: If you go to color management > view transform. Is it set to standard when you render it?

Comment: @dogking57 Yes, View Transform under Color Management is set to Standard with all its default settings. I did not touch that.

Comment: If I understand right, you have the images already rendered and just want to combine them. You can import images as planes (got the idea from a website) and render it if that would work better. I'm really not sure what setting is affecting your render negatively. If you scaled down the resolution, maybe your wouldn't see the rings too much. I'm not too much of an expert on view transform, but if your image sequence was rendered using the filmic transform, maybe go back to that to render the video.

Comment: @dogking57 As I mentioned earlier, I have not changed anything in the color management section, so it remains as "Standard" both in image render and video render. I mean, we can keep that out of the suspect list. Your idea of importing the images as planes and render as video, sounds good, but too heavy to try out with 20 thousands images that I have. In other words, even if it works with a small test sample, I cannot definitely do that for the actual product (unless there is some easy way to import images in bulk and automate the process, which I am not aware of right now). Thanks anyway!